# How is percentage calculated when using it for margin and padding?

Tags: html, css, margin, padding

I need help understanding how the percentage is calculated when a div has no parent div, and we use percentage for its margin and padding. For example

```
<div id="q1" class="question"><p>Universal Containers was bought by a larger company   and needs to provide information on a
monthly basis to the new parent company to help predict sales.</p>
<p>Which data should the new parent company review?</p>
<ol>
<li>Dashboard of user login history</li>
<li>Count of new records created</li>
<li>Number of activities tied to opportunities</li>
<li>Opportunity pipeline report grouped by month</li>
</ol>
<p>The answer is 4</p>
</div>
```

That div sits directly into the body tag, there's no other div. Here's the CSS

```
.question{background-color:#F5F5DC;
background-image: url(/pgonzalez/demo-project/html/Images/imageedit_6_5296743467.png);
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-position:center;
border-width: 1px;
padding-top:0.1%;
padding-bottom:0.1%;
margin-bottom:1%;
padding-left:1%;
border-radius: 25px; /*makes the borders round*/
margin-right:40%; /*prevents the div from "touching" the right side of the browser   screen*/}
```

Although I'm getting the desired behavior, I don't understand why, for example the margin-right is 40%. 40% of what? I understand it's based on the parent element but because it sits directly into the body, I'm not sure I understand how it gets calculated. The same applies padding.

I know the question has been asked before and I did my homework before posting, I've also been trying to find a good article on the subject but haven't found any that would answer this specific question. If you could answer the question or point to a good resource that I can use to understand how % are always calculated, I'd appreciate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when you specify `margin-right:40%;` , it means 40% of parent element. In you case it is `body` element. By default, `width` of body is 100% of your screen size.

To understand more about margin, please refer http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/box.html#margin-properties

Comment: Exactly, I understand it comes from the body, but the body as far as I know, doesn't have any explicit size, margin, etc...maybe it depends on the browser? I will read the article you provided and see if it answers the question. Thank you.

Comment: I guess by default body has margin:8px; and rest is body width, which is equal to screen size and when you specify 40%, it is 40% of parent width(in this case 40% of body width)

Comment: Thank you very much Anish, that's exactly what I needed to know. I will play with this a bit more to confirm what you described. Thanks!

Comment: I confirmed with the Google Chrome "Elements" tab that the body's width is in accordance to the browser window. If you re size your browser window, the width is automatically adjusted.Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

Margin and padding set with a % value will use width of parent's , that it is a vertical or horizontal rule :). This might confuse you.

http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/box.html#propdef-margin-top

http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/box.html#propdef-padding-top

Young browser can use vw and vh units to refer to window's width and height.

http://dev.w3.org/csswg/css-values/#viewport-relative-lengths

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like something within your whole code that is causing it? Should probably fiddle the page for a in-depth explanation.

Comment: I'm happy with the result. The question is, if margin-right is 40%? of the body, how is that 40% calculated? Based on which property of the body? The body doesn't have any explicit size, width, etc., so how is it calculated?

Comment: defaut width used is 100% of width avalaible of parent if unset : http://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/GrExy